# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not be visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We have updated the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We have updated some of the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We have fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We are launching the shiny new user profile!

Visually it will "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: I'm guessing it's too late but thought it might be worth a mention. Any chance something can be done about this at the same time? http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/can-we-get-a-hyperlink-style-for-chat-that-is-less-subtle

Comment: Thinking about it chat probably isn't affected by the new changes but I don't know for sure :)

Comment: @SpartanDonut chat isn't part of the update, but I will ping someone who might be able to make that adjustment.

Answer (score 6):

Wooo yessss. ♥ *It's so pretty I want to touch it.*

---

On the subject of touching:

At 100% zoom Chromium on Linux, the *Questions*-button is almost touching the title:

[image: SO CLOSE]

At 75% zoom, it overlaps:

[image: TOO CLOSE]

I did some dev-tools digging in case it's useful: The button's `font-family` is hitting `sans-serif`, which on my system (and probably some other Linuxes), defaults to the generously-spaced [DejaVu Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts).

I often browse zoomed out and didn't notice this on the old design.